# Globbing in C++/C, on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, glob

Is there a *smooth* way to glob in C or C++ in Windows?

E.g., myprogram.exe *.txt sends my program an ARGV list that has...ARGV[1]=`*.txt` in it.

I would like to be able to have a function (let's call it readglob) that takes a string and returns a vector of strings, each containing a filename.

This way, if I have files `a.txt b.txt c.txt` in my directory and readglob gets an argument `*.txt`, it returns the above filelist.

```
//Prototype of this hypothetical function.
vector<string> readglob(string);
```

Does such exist?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Link with `setargv.obj` (or `wsetargv.obj`) and argv[] will be globbed for you similar to how the Unix shells do it:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bch7bkk.aspx

I can't vouch for how well it does it though.

Comment: Terribly non-cross-platform, but it's easy and it Just Works.

Comment: It doesn't have to be cross-platform because only Win32 has this problem! Great tip.

Comment: Just tried it myself. Works like a champ. Couldn't be easier.

Answer (score 4):

This is very Windows-specific. I don't know how you'd write this to be cross-platform. But I've used this in Windows programs and it works well for me.

```
// Change to the specified working directory
string path;
cout << "Enter the path to report: ";
cin >> path;
_chdir(path.c_str());

// Get the file description
string desc;
cout << "Enter the file description: ";
cin >> desc;

// List the files in the directory
intptr_t file;
_finddata_t filedata;
file = _findfirst(desc.c_str(),&filedata);
if (file != -1)
{
  do
  {
    cout << filedata.name << endl;
    // Or put the file name in a vector here
  } while (_findnext(file,&filedata) == 0);
}
else
{
  cout << "No described files found" << endl;
}
_findclose(file);
```

Comment: don't use pre/code tags, instead just highlight the code and click on the button with 1/0's on it. It'll make it show up as code.

Comment: +1 for code; I've selected Michael's answer because it's much simpler. :-)

Comment: simple and useful. THX

Comment: It would help to state the required header files of your code.

Answer (score 2):

there was talk about having it in Boost::filesystem but it was dropped in favor of using the boost::regex.

For win32 specific (MFC) you can use the [CFileFind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618(VS.80).aspx) class

Comment: That's a bummer. Doing a quick test using cl <myprogramname> & #including afx.h results in an link error relating to new. +1 for the link, but I don't want to eat up my evening working on making MFC work for me.

Comment: Seems that for non-MFC stuff, you can use FindFirstFile and friends to do it with straight win32 code.

Comment: MFC is mostly wrappers around win32 calls, couldn't remember the FindFirstFile(), it all comes back to me now.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way now, but last time I had to deal with this problem I ended up including [Henry Spencer's regex library](http://arglist.com/regex/) statically linked into my program (his library is BSD licensed), and then I made a wrapper class that converted the user's glob-expressions into regular expressions to feed to the regex code.  You can view/grab the wrapper class [here](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/html/classmuscle_1_1StringMatcher.html) if you like.

Once you have those parts in place, the final thing to do is actually read the directory, and pass each entry name into the matching function to see if it matches the expression or not.  The filenames that match, you add to your vector; the ones that don't you discard.  Reading the directory is fairly straightforward to do using the DOS _findfirst() and _findnext() functions, but if you want a nicer C++ interface I have a [portable wrapper](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/html/classmuscle_1_1Directory.html) class for that also...

Answer (score 0):

Ehw.  I had to implement something like this in ANSI C about 15 years ago.  Start with the ANSI opendir/readdir routines, I guess.  Globs aren't exactly RegExs, so you will have to implement your own filtering.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883594/microsoft-visual-studio-opendir-and-readdir-how opendir/readir aren't in Visual Studio.

Comment: Drat!  those must be POSIX, not ANSI.  Whatever happened to the Win NT POSIX layer???