# Accepting a wildcard to open a file

Tags: c, file, wildcard

OK this is embarrassing and as much as I hate to, I have no other option.  I don't know C but I was presented with a problem that I need to solve and although I've done some researching the time it would take me to modify the program myself is just too much so I have to swallow my pride (and I'm guessing some rep pts) to ask for help.

This is a simple program to convert a unix file to dos, the only problem is that I need it to accept wildcards (eg.. c:/>unix2dos *.txt  or file*.txt ) Nothing fancy.

Here is the code that I have now..

```
    // UNIX2DOS - a Win32 utility to convert single text files from Unix to MS-DOS format.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/utime.h>

#ifndef TRUE
#   define TRUE  (1)
#   define FALSE (0)
#endif

#define R_CNTRL   "rb"
#define W_CNTRL   "wb"

struct stat s_buf;

int u2dos (path)
char *path;
{
    FILE *in, *out;
    int ch,
        prev_ch= 0, 
        rval = FALSE;
    char temppath [16];
    struct _utimbuf ut_buf;
    strcpy (temppath, "./clntmp");
    strcat (temppath, "XXXXXX");
    mktemp (temppath);
    if ((in=fopen (path, R_CNTRL)) == (FILE *) 0)
        return TRUE;
    if ((out=fopen (temppath, W_CNTRL)) == (FILE *) 0)
    {
        fclose (in);
        return TRUE;
    }

    #define LF        0x0A
    #define CR        0x0D

    while ((ch = getc (in)) != EOF)
    {
        if (    ( ch == LF)
             && ( prev_ch != CR)
             && ( putc( CR, out) == EOF)
             || ( putc( ch, out) == EOF)
           )
        {
            rval = TRUE;
            break;
        }
        prev_ch= ch ;
    }

    if (fclose (in) == EOF)
    {
        rval = TRUE;
    }
    if (fclose (out) == EOF)
    {
        rval = TRUE;
    }
    ut_buf.actime = s_buf.st_atime;
    ut_buf.modtime = s_buf.st_mtime;
    if (_utime (temppath, &ut_buf) == -1)
        rval = TRUE;
    if (unlink (path) == -1)
        rval = TRUE;
    if (rval)
    {
        unlink (temppath);
        return TRUE;
    }
    if (rename (temppath,path) == -1)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unix2Dos: Problems renaming '%s' to '%s'.\n", temppath, path);
        fprintf (stderr, "          However, file '%s' remains.\n", temppath);
        exit (1);
    }
    unlink (temppath);
    return FALSE;
}

void main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    char *path;
    while (--argc>0)
    {
        if (stat (path=*++argv, &s_buf) != -1)
        {
            printf ("Unix2Dos: Processing file %s ...\n", path);
            if (u2dos (path))
            {
                fprintf (stderr, "Unix2Dos: Problems processing file %s.\n", path);
                exit (1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Unix2Dos: Can't stat '%s'.\n", path);
            exit (1);
        }
    }
}
```

I cant believe I have digressed to one of the "Send me da codez" people I have grown to despise but right now it seems like this is my best option.

I'm going to go burry my head in the sand now.  Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Although implied, I thought I should make the question obvious.  Can you please provide some assistance in modifying this program to accept wildcard variables in a windows environment?

Comment: I'd say it's not "Send me da codez" because you clearly have made some research effort before posting this

Comment: Here you'll find a couple of win32 solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269480/globbing-in-c-c-on-windows

Comment: Is this meant to run on Windows or Unix?

Comment: Windows, Ive read in other posts that Unix would be able to handle the wildcard.

Comment: Instead of hard coding the values defined in `LF` and `CR` use character literals like `'\n'` and `'\r'`. Also, is there any specific reason to use K&R definitions in functions?

Comment: Unfortunately this isnt my program, and I know very little (if nothing at all) about C which is why Im here asking for help.  I probably shouldnt even be poking my nose into this problem but Im just trying to help out a friend.

Answer (score 4):

*nix shells, (e.g. bash), automatically expand wildcard arguments. Windows shell does not. But Microsoft Visual C runtime library does have an option to do it automatically on your program's startup. How to do it is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bch7bkk.aspx). Basically you need to link against setargv.obj.

Answer (score 4):

Since this will run on Windows, you can use FindFirstFile, FindNextFile and FindClose.  There is an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx

Comment: ...because the Windows API is so intuitive and easy to work with when you have little to no experience of the C language  :)  But yeah, indeed those are the functions to use when searching for and listing files.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to reinvent a whole bunch of wheels to use wildcards in the file names, and even more to do it portably. Try using cygwin's `bash` and `unix2dos`.

Comment: That would be ideal, but I would like to automate the process on Win 2003 Server.   If its as difficult than you say, then I might have to find a different solution like changing the file name to a constant first, then running the program. ..but this could have some implications too.   Thanks for the help  +1

Comment: +1 a bash script can be run with cygwin in a relatively easily automated way.  We've got cygwin running on a number of servers at work, bash is such an amazing step up from the windows shell and batch files.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the program as is, and let some (.)bat(ch) file magic do the expansion of wildcards?

On how to do this please see here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/68268/en-us

Although you'd be starting a new process for each file to be converted, which is quiet expensive, it'll keep you from hacking around using a language you do not seem to like ... ;-)