# How to determine users input "*" at command line to indicate multiple files in C

Tags: c, arguments, argc

for example if the user type in the command line

> match "hello" test*in

it means find the "the" in all .in type of files with name "test".

```
bool containMany=false;
int i;
for(i= 0; arguments[i]; i++){

    printf("ARGUMENTS  %s\n",arguments[i]);
    if(strstr(arguments[i],"*")){
        containMany=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

but it does not work. The arguments are:

> ARGUMENT match
>
> ARGUMENT hello
>
> ARGUMENT test0.in
>
> ARGUMENT test1.in
>
> ARGUMENT test2.in

So how I make containMany become true when the user type "*" ?

Comment: Your shell has already done the substitution for you.

Comment: Anyway, to pass in a *literal* `*`, write it as `match test\*in` or `match 'test*in'` in sh-like shells.

Comment: I am using cmd.exe/windows...

Comment: Where does the `arguments` array come from?

Comment: what else can I do if writing match test\*in or 'test*in' is not allowed?

Comment: @MartinR the arguments is a char** global variable.. I declared it..

Comment: @GavinZ.: Where/how is that global arguments variable *set*?

Comment: @MartinR on the very top of the program I declared char **arguments, and in the main function I wrote arguments=argv.

Comment: @GavinZ.: OK. But that is strange, because I am also quite sure that cmd.exe on Windows does no wildcard expansion of the arguments.

Comment: @ruakh, @Martin R: the MinGW runtime performs glob expansion on the command line.  Also, if you link in `setargv.obj` in MSVC you'll get glob expansion from the command line (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1269533/12711).

Comment: @MartinR sigh.. I always got these strange things happen to me.. it's not my first time got answers like this..

Answer (score 2):

That's because your shell automatically makes glob-style substitutions. If you don't want shell to do that enclose the input arguments in single quotes or use backslash.

If your working dir has files A and B then this expression:

```
test *
```

would be replaced with

```
test A B
```

**before** test gets executed.

If, on the other hand you run like this:

```
test '*'
```

or like this:

```
test \*
```

then there will be no shell substitution, and your program will actually see the star.

Comment: what can I do if using '*' or \\* is not allowed?

Comment: @GavinZ. Switch to using a libc that *doesn't* do glob expansion (e.g. MSVC, non-mingw gcc?). Then realize it's just a hack, as "proper shells" will do glob expansion *anyway* ..

Comment: @GavinZ., not allowed by what or by whom? It's fairly common to use quotes or backslash; for example, "find <dir> -name <pattern>" is almost always used with quotes or backslash in the <pattern>. If you run your program from shell, or by using commands such as "system", then glob will happen anyway. If you are executing from another program, they you can use "exec" or "spawn", which won't do substitution, although, as user2864740, that may not be desirable.

Comment: @Michael - I think he means "what can I do if using '*' or \* doesn't work?".  Apparently he is using MinGW on Windows.

Comment: @Michael: well, i'm sorry to say that it's not allowed by the assignment requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally the shell performs wildcard expansion on the command line - that's the way it's done on Unix-style platforms.  If no expansion is desired, the user must typically quote the argument that contains the wildcard character or escape the wildard character.

On Windows, the `command.com`/`cmd.exe` shell do *not* perform filename expansion. However:

- the MinGW toochain's runtime *does* perform expansion of filename wildcards.  To disable this behavior, link in `CRT_noglob.o` or add the zero-initialized global variable `int _CRT_glob = 0;` to one of your .c files to disable the runtime's glob expansion.
- MSVC includes an object file, `setargv.obj` that will cause the runtime to expand the command line filename wildcards, if that's the behavior you want.