# Determining files in a directory

Tags: c++, posix

I come from a C# background and I am working on a C++ project.  I need to open files in a directory, then process that data in the files.  The problem is on my target environment (Greenhills Integrity), I cannot access a "directory".  It seems C++ does not have a concept of a directory.  Why not?  This problem is simple in C#.  I cannot link to any big library(BOOST or dirent) to get the files.  I can open a file using fopen, but I won't always know the file names, so I have to "strcat" the directory to each filename in order to "fopen" the files.

I need a way to just get the file names in a directory without using an external API.  Is that possible?

Comment: In C++ there is no notion of a directory.  The underlying system treats files and directories the same - as "handles."  IIRC there is a flag on a filesystem handle which indicates if it's a directory (look at the stat function.)

Comment: Added `posix` tag since Greenhills Integrity supports POSIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. C++ has no "built-in" directory functionality - you need to use a library of some sort.

Comment: Of course it's possible.  While C++ doesn't have any specific directory classes (like the file streams) you can just the underlying system calls - readdir et al. http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node20.html

Comment: readdir isn't  a system call. All I/O in C++ (as in C) is prerformed via libraries.

Answer (score 4):

The major C++ APIs have directories.  Start with [readdir](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html) on POSIX or [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx)() on Windows.  Greenhills seems to [support POSIX](http://www.ghs.com/products/rtos/integrity_rtos_features.html#posix).

Comment: Maybe someone thought that hints for accomplishing something on Win32 and Unix aren't all that helpful for someone hacking on Greenhills Integrity? Mind you, while it wasn't me, I wouldn't blame them.

Comment: I initially down-voted because readdir is not a generic C++ function; however have re-upvoted since the edit to indicate the required function is operating specific.

Answer (score 2):

Check with your operating system. Directory handling is different for each. You will have to use the Windows 32 API if you want to list/query directories on Microsoft Windows, and the Linux API (e.g. opendir/stat) if you want to list/query directories on Linux.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883594/microsoft-visual-studio-opendir-and-readdir-how