# Is given name is file or directory while looping a directory structure in C++

Tags: c++, c

In C++, how can we find programatically while looping thourhg a directory structure if it is subdirectory or is it a file. This i want to perform with functions avaialble in C++ standard, with out using Boost or system call and implementaiton should be portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a portable library (boost comes to mind) you will not be able to do this *portably* (pun may be intended). The c++ standard does not have this type of functionality.

Why do you not want to use boost?

Answer (score 0):

The readdir() function from the standard C library should do the trick. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir for some basic documentation of it.

The dirent struct should contain the necessary information to tell the type of each file.

Comment: I believe that `readdir()` is not standard C but rather POSIX. At any rate I don't think it can be used in windows with Visual Studio directly.

Comment: Hm, 'man readdir' on my OSX machine says "Standard C Library", but perhaps it's referring to "libc the binary on disk" rather than "the C library spec". I'm unfamiliar with the Windows APIs, so I won't be much help beyond that.

Comment: I am not sure about it, I don't code in windows either, but looking at the C99 draft I did not find it, and google search for "readdir windows" shows that some people have tried and are [looking for alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883594/microsoft-visual-studio-opendir-and-readdir-how).