# Get all file names from dir

Tags: c, file, dir

Is there a way to get the names of all files inside a directory using C?

Comment: It's OS dependent.

Comment: Right, ANSI C does not specify a method for listing directory contents. You need to specify whether you need code for Windows or a POSIX system.

Comment: ...or MacOS, or Android, or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While C itself does not specify a way (or even specify directories), POSIX does. You can either use `opendir` and `readdir` yourself to read an entry at a time, or you can use `scandir` or `glob` to get the results all together in memory (and filter which entries get listed).

Answer (score 1):

See [readdir()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) on Unix or for Windows see [Microsoft Visual Studio: opendir() and readdir(), how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883594/microsoft-visual-studio-opendir-and-readdir-how)