# error lnk2001: closedir, readdir, opendir

Tags: c++, unix, dirent.h

I am trying to import a c++ project from linux to windows (vs2010). My problem arise with the use of dirent.h. I ve downloaded the windows version of dirent from here: [dirent](http://softagalleria.net/dirent.php). However when I compile my project I am getting the following errors:

```
1>DBreading.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _closedir
1>DBreading.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _readdir
1>DBreading.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _opendir
```

A little research and I found that I am using some unix functions. My code is:

```
#include <DBreading.h>
#include <Detection.h>

#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#undef _POSIX_SOURCE

DBreading::DBreading(){}

vector <string> DBreading::listFile(string path){

    vector<string> directories;

    DIR *pDIR;
    const char * c = path.c_str();
    struct dirent *entry;
    if( pDIR=opendir(c) ){
        while(entry = readdir(pDIR)){
        if( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0 )
            //cout << entry->d_name << "\n";
            directories.push_back( entry->d_name);
        }
        closedir(pDIR);
    }

    // directories stores all subfolders or sub-files of a given path directory
    return directories;
}
```

Any idea which are the correspondant function for closedir readdir and opendir in windows?

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: myProject, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  DBreading.cpp
1>DBreading.cpp(46): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(52): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(53): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(90): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(97): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(116): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(122): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(123): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(159): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.cpp(166): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>  Detection.cpp
1>c:\opencv-2.4.6.1\install\include\opencv2\flann\logger.h(66): warning C4996: 'fopen':    
 This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable   
 deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
  1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdio.h(234) :
 see 
declaration of 'fopen'
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp(120): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>main.cpp(166): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>main.cpp(182): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>main.cpp(206): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>main.cpp(268): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>DBreading.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _closedir
1>DBreading.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _readdir
1>DBreading.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _opendir
1>C:\Documents and Settings\chrathan.ITI-THERMI\My Documents\Visual Studio    
2010\Projects\myProject\Release\myProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved
```

Comment: Please, show what is your link line/options.

Comment: I beg your pardon? Diego, what you mean with link line/options?

Comment: Compilation implies the compilation phase and the linking phase. The first one produces object modules (.o), and the final phase links all these with system libraries to produce an executable. I would like to see how you generated the final executable. You may be missing some linker option to include the POSIX DLL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual Studio: opendir() and readdir(), how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883594/microsoft-visual-studio-opendir-and-readdir-how)

Comment: You are trying to use Unix/Linux functionality that doesn't exist (directly, in that form) in Windows. See duplicate question.

Comment: What about this API http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile`, and `FindClose` (I believe these are in windows.h).

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28VS.85%29.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly link to an implementation of `dirent.h` that wraps the Windows functions in the Unix API. (Calling that "the Windows version" is a bit missing the point.)

What *should* be happening is that you include that header, and when you are *calling* `readdir()` etc., that call is turned (by the code in your `dirent.h`) into Windows API calls like `FindNextFileW()` etc. -- no Unix functions actually being involved.

The point is, I don't see your source example actually *including* `dirent.h`... unless you do the include somewhere we cannot see it, that means you *installed* that wrapping header, but you are not *using* it. Instead you `#include` some POSIX headers, which in turn reference the appropriate *POSIX* functions (which your linker does not find).

Mix & mingle of Windows and POSIX API. A sure recipee for disaster.

You need to adjust your `#include`'s accordingly. As your example isn't [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: I have add dirent.h to include paths in project properties.

Comment: @FereRes: Adding the *path* to the *include path* means that MSVC can *find* the header **if you `#include <dirent.h>`**. If you don't include it in your source, adding the path to the project properties won't do anything. (That's the equivalent of the `-I` option for GCC.) Can it be that you are in waters much too deep for your current grasp of the language and its toolchain? ;-)

Comment: It's not that case, I ve already tried to include dirent.h but I am getting the same errors.

Comment: @FereRes: Are you sure you are including the *right* `dirent.h`? Check your assumptions. Put an `#error This is the right one!` in the header and see if this makes the compilation abort. If it does, step back and follow the "SSCCE" link in my answer, because otherwise we'll be playing ping-pong all day. ;)