# readdir_r() function in Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, readdir, dirent.h

I am trying to build c++ ported code of libphonenumber library in windows using Visual studio. Some of its code use readdir_r() which is defined in dirent.h file.

Visual studio does not contain any dirent.h file. So after exploring I found solution that I can copy dirent.h file into "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\include".

But all dirent.h file for window contain readdir() but not readdir_r(). Also fucntion signature is different.

Can I get dirent.h for windows as same in Linux. Which contain readdir_r()???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual Studio: opendir() and readdir(), how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883594/microsoft-visual-studio-opendir-and-readdir-how)

Comment: I am asking about readdir_r(). Signature of readdir() and readdir_r() is different. I have solution to readdir() but I am finding about readdir_r(). Both are available in dirent.h file.

Comment: But you are not using Linux so you need to adopt a different approach

Comment: @Ed Heal: Google's libphonenumber library in C++ already use this function. They provide step to build in Visual Studio 2010. https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/cpp I just following them.