# Is there a windows equivalent to the functionality of sys/dir.h?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I am working on making a linux c++ project compile and run on Windows. I have run into some problems with sys/dir.h and am struggling to find a windows equivalent. Does anyone know the most similar Windows library in terms of functionality?

I have looked around online and can't find a solid solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: C++ has `std::filesystem` for interacting with the filesytem. Trying to find a direct code-compatible header is asking for trouble.

Comment: what are you using from `sys/dir.h` that you need to port to windows?

Comment: Some potential 'drop-in' replacements here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883594/microsoft-visual-studio-opendir-and-readdir-how

Comment: @AlanBirtles I need to use openDir, closeDir, readDir, and rewindDir, mainly.

Comment: `NtOpenFile`, `NtClose`, `NtQueryDirectoryFile`

Comment: For Winapi (not NT native API), `FirstFirstFile` / `FindNextFile`.  Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory